# Python MySQLdb print row(s) from Table A where not in Table B

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I have two tables, `sales_olap` and `resellers`

I need to print out what reseller from `sales_olap` does not exist in `resellers` table

for instance:

```
result = cursor.execute("SELECT SO.reseller_name FROM sales_olap AS SO WHERE 
SO.reseller_name!=(SELECT reseller FROM resellers)")
for row in result:
    print row
```

but I am getting an error of: `1242, Subquery returns more than 1 row`

How can I get it to only print the reseller names from `sales_olap` table where they do not exist in `resellers` table?

If I try doing:

```
    result = cursor.execute("SELECT reseller_name FROM sales_olap WHERE reseller_name NOT IN(SELECT reseller FROM resellers)")
    for row in result:
        print row['reseller_name']
```

Then I get the error of: `TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get this working by doing it this way:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT reseller_name FROM sales_olap LEFT JOIN resellers ON sales_olap.reseller_name=resellers.reseller WHERE resellers.reseller IS NULL")
result = cursor.fetchall()

for row, in result:
    print (row)
```